# Fixing format of print statement

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, string, printing

I recently just started working with document builder to build a title with my XML. This is the following code I am using right now:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\staff.xml"));
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();       
    Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stw));
    String xmldata = (stw.toString());
    System.out.println(xmldata);
```

It builds the title fine, but it starts writing the XML file on the same line due to the parse. Can someone show me how I can alter this code to get `<company>` onto the second line?
Here is my print:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><company>
    <comp id="512">
        <firstname>Brandon</firstname>
        <lastname>Liens</lastname>
        <empid>612</empid>
        <rqid>51265</rqid>
    </comp>
</company>
```

Staff.XML file:

```
<company>
    <comp id="512">
        <firstname>Brandon</firstname>
        <lastname>Nyberg</lastname>
        <empid>612</empid>
        <rqid>51265</rqid>
    </comp>
</company>
```

Comment: So there is a linebreak in the source file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a newline after the XML declaration automatically, but if you can deal with removing the XML declaration entirely, you can add this line just after your `Transformer serializer = ...` line:

```
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

Comment: It is not possible to have the XML declaration above the xml file? As in a simple break \n without editing the staff file?

Comment: You can manually print out your own XML declaration, then print a newline directly, then the document that's generated with `OMIT_XML_DECLARATION`. :-)

Comment: Sounds perfect Chris. I greatly appreciate the help as I've been trying to do it with the XML Declaration included. Thanks!